# How can I position text over image each other in a stack?

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I've been trying to create a little card in flutter, and I've been trying to get the hang of stacks and how to position items over each other. I've moved the items around each other within the code a ton, but I can't seem to figure out how to position the text over the image, as shown. Any help on how to do this would be fantastic!

[image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwFCu.png)

```
 body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                      Center(
                        child: InkWell(
                            onTap: null,
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              height: 200,
                              width: 300,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                    end: Alignment.topRight,
                                    colors: [Colors.red, Colors.redAccent],
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                              child: Column(),
                            )),
                      ),
                      Center(
                          child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              child: Image.asset(
                                'assets/running.png',
                                height: 180,
                                width: 300,
                              ))),
                      Center(
                          child: Text(
                        "Events",
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 30),
                      )),
                    ]))
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Stack` Widget with below code

```
 Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/jitesh.jpg'),
              )),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Text(
            'jitesh',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
          )),
        ],
      ),
```